Presigned-url QR-Code - Python - AWS s3 bucket
In my project, I'm upload some images in a s3 bucket, and generating qr-code in order to download the picture.
I would like to download directly the picture, instead of being redirected to the url.
When I scan the QR-Code I see the name of the s3 bucket, but I would like to see a prompt asking me to save the image or automatically downloaded to a folder inside the phone.
Here you have the code snippet:
 def generate_upload_presigned_url(self, filename, bucket_name, expiration_time=3600):
        """Generates a presigned URL for uploading a file to S3 with Content-Disposition header."""
        try:
            object_key = f"{uuid.uuid4()}{os.path.splitext(filename)[1]}"
            # headers = {
            #     'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename="{quote_plus(filename)}"'
            # }
            headers = {
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment'
            }
            params = {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': object_key, 'ContentDisposition': headers['Content-Disposition']}
            presigned_url = self.s3_client.generate_presigned_url('put_object',
                                                                Params=params,
                                                                ExpiresIn=expiration_time)
            return {
                'signed_url': presigned_url,
                'public_url': f"https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/{object_key}",
                'headers': headers
            }
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error generating presigned URL: {e}")
            return None

The QR Code is inside a S3 Bucket, and I should be able to download the picture before the expiration_time.

Welcome to StackOverflow, what does your code currently do? How have you tried to solve it? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
